# ANTLR Parsing - Matches Wrong Thing but Fix is EOF?

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4

I try to parse:

```
return 3 + 4;
```

My parse code (see below) parses it as the second rule (`statement statements program`) instead of the first rule. If I comment out the second rule, then the parser interprets it as the third rule (`functions statement program`).

My "fix" that has worked so far is to make:

```
master : program EOF ;
```

Why does that fix my issue?

Relevant Parse Code:

```
program
    : statement { 
        System.out.println("STATEMENT PROGRAM");
      }     
    | statement statements program {
        System.out.println("MULTI STATEMENT PROGRAM");
      }
    | functions statement program {
        System.out.println("FUNCTION PROGRAM");
      };

statement :
   RETURN expr SEMICOLON {
        System.out.println("STATEMENT");
   };
```

Note: 'statements' and 'functions' can be nullable

Also, assume `expr` is correct :)   (it cannot be nullable)

Some clarification:

```
statements : statement* ;
```

When I run `parser.program()`, I expect that `return 3 + 4;` should parse properly (and then the `EOF` comes after which is not caught by any parse rules); however, `return 'return 3 + 4;'` is not treated as a statement but a `statement statements program`.

Commenting out that rule, my parser still does not parse `return 3 + 4;` as a `statement` but as a `functions statement program`.

I would think that the return statement is parsed as

```
statement='return 3 + 4;' EOF
```

and not

```
statement='return 3 + 4;' statements='' program=?
```

and also not

```
functions='' statement='return 3 + 4;' program=?
```

My question is, why is ANTLR trying to parse it as the second and third rules?

Comment: I'm confused and I'm not sure there's enough information here to help you. Why does your `program` allow the existence of child `program`s inside it? What have you defined for the `statements` (plural) and `functions` rules? In any case, don't you *want* `EOF` at the end, or are inputs allowed to end in junk-data?

Comment: I added some clarification. Also, what I wrote down for the possible parsing is what ANTLR is trying to parse it as.

Comment: I think answering this question might require seeing the *whole* grammar. (If you have ANTLRWorks 2, you can also run it in the test-rig and see a generated tree representation of what it's doing.)

Comment: I believe this is because `*` operator is greedy. Using `EOF` could solve it and you should always add `EOF` at the end of first grammar rule.

Comment: What'S the rule for `program`?