# ANTLR matches part of a parser rule even though it fails to fully match the rule

Tags: c#, parsing, antlr, dsl

I am starting out with ANTLR and trying to make a parser for a very simple language.
Currently my grammar is defined as:

```
/*
 * Parser Rules
 */

public compileUnit
    : DEFINE IDENTIFIER END_OF_STATEMENT { Console.WriteLine($IDENTIFIER.text); };

/*
 * Lexer Rules
 */


DEFINE : 'define';

// Basic tokens
INT : '0'..'9'+;

END_OF_STATEMENT : ';';

// Whitespace
WS :  (' '|'\t'|'\r'|'\n')+ {Skip();} ;

// Sub-statement tokens

IDENTIFIER : ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z')+ (INT | ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z') | '_')*;
```

The language is `CSharp3`.

When I try to input the following, it works correctly, printing the identifier name:

```
define My_Identifier1;
```

However, the input `garbage` also causes `garbage` to be printed out as if it were an identifier.

Why does `compileUnit` not throw an exception?
Could this be an issue with the order in which the grammar rules are defined?

Comment: You mean word "garbage"? Because your rule for identifier allows it. Btw. your regex for identifier is odd -- it should be `('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z') (INT | 'a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '_')*` at least.

Comment: Oops you're right the plus should not be there.

Comment: The input "garbage" should be rejected. Only "define garbage;" should be allowed

Comment: From now on the guessing part starts because I don't know about ANTLR (I use my own C# NLT suite -- https://sourceforge.net/projects/naivelangtools/) but I would print out what was grabbed by `DEFINE` terminal. You know, as simple debugging. Just make sure you print `$DEFINE.text # $IDENTIFIER.text` (any separator will suffice, except for space) to make sure you know which part is which.

Comment: When I print out the value of the define token on a correct input it prints "define". When doing it on the "garbage" input it prints "missing define".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this problem was to change the parser rule to be (note the addition of the `EOF` token):

```
public compileUnit
: DEFINE IDENTIFIER END_OF_STATEMENT EOF { Console.WriteLine($IDENTIFIER.text); };
```

And override the ReportError method of the parser class.

```
public override void ReportError(Antlr.Runtime.RecognitionException e)
{
    base.ReportError(e);
    throw e;
}
```

Now, the calling code has access to the exception and development can continue.

It is worth pointing out that after stumbling on the solution I did a quick search and located [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18952397/antlr-parsing-matches-wrong-thing-but-fix-is-eof) which seems to be similar. This seems not to be a very obvious part of ANTLR (ie. how ANTLR handles BNF grammars) and a potential stumbling block for newcomers to the platform.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the record, if you would like to switch, this is how it would like in NLT, there are some minor differences, but nothing hard to to grasp.

```
/*
 * Parser Rules
 */
compileUnit -> DEFINE id:IDENTIFIER END_OF_STATEMENT 
               {{ Console.WriteLine(id); return null; }};

/*
 * Lexer Rules
 */

"define" -> DEFINE;
/[0-9]+/ -> INT,Convert.ToInt32($text);
";" -> END_OF_STATEMENT;

// Whitespace
/[ \\t\\r\\n]+/ { };

// Sub-statement tokens
/[a-zA-z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*/ -> IDENTIFIER;
```

*It is just a draft.*

Comment: I decided to stick with ANTLR as it is already in my project, but for reference see my answer below with the solution to the problem.